# Show or hide password - icon or textual?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, password, toggle

Allowing the user to toggle visibility is becoming a more standardised part of forms, and in my opinion for good reason. I'm however unsure what the best way to denote this ability is; an icon or a togglable label? If hamburgers are already not always recognized, I can imagine that this would be even worse for this feature, especially which *status* it is currently showing.

My question: is there any research about what works better; a hide/show label or an icon that visually shows the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If hamburgers are already not always recognized

Its not 2005 anymore, people have learned about the hamburger icon.

> My question: is there any research about what works better; a hide/show label or an icon that visually shows the same?

Combine an icon with text for the best results. 
For example an eye with the label "Show password" and a crossed eye with the label "Hide password".

Text works better then icons alone since most icons are not universally understood but if you don't have space problems icon + text is the best way to go.

Good read: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/

Comment: You'd be surprised how much users get stuck on forms here..  I'll check and see if I can use both label and icon simultaneously, it would definitely solve the problem.